# Compass comile, get an error "LoadError on line ["54"]"

Tags: ruby, compass

I'm new with compass, an di Want to compile a scss file.

```
 compass compile
```

I Get this error

```
Ignoring ffi-1.9.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.10
LoadError on line ["54"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

This is my trace
compass compile --trace

```
      /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:179:in `require'
  /Users/bob/Documents/Lavori/giunti_prod/drupal/sites/all/themes/gpunto/config.rb:28:in `get_binding'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:207:in `with_defaults'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:19:in `configuration_for'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:69:in `add_project_configuration'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried to install gem with brew, and in my `~/.zshrc` I Added

```
export RBENV_ROOT="$(brew --prefix rbenv)"

export GEM_HOME="$(brew --prefix)/opt/gems"

export GEM_PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/gems"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late for this answer but I just encounter the same problem. What worked for me was:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem uninstall compass
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

make sure you remove al sass versions